# Rewrite Rule don't let me access my domain's index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

In my page, when I write the url domain.com/abc it uses the htaccess RewriteRule ( posted below) and opens the  company-profile.php page, showing the ABC profile. **ABC IS AN EXAMPLE. IT MAY BE ANYTHING**

However, even I have a domain.com/index.php file, when I write just domain.com and hit enter, it takes me to the *company-profile.php* page where it supposed to show the *index.php* file

My question is how can I fix this ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)?$ /domain.com/company-profile.php?cid=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.(php|html?)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile/company-profile.php?cid=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, then you've got some other rewriterules screwing things up for you. Therefore I suggest you to post all of your htaccess file instead of just the one line you think is causing the problem

Comment: Yes I should have done that. I updated my question with full htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your `RewriteRule` is matching *anything* that's a combination of letters and numbers and passing it to your `/domain.com/profile/company-profile.php` script. You need to be more specific on your `RewriteRule`, i.e:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/profile/([a-z0-9]+)?$ /domain.com/profile/company-profile.php?cid=$1 [NC,L]
```

The above will only match requests beginning with `/profile/`, so for example `/profile/martinbean` will be matched.

Comment: Thank you for this, but I don't want this solution.Isn't there a workaround to keep it `domain.com/abc` ? I am sure there must be something, maybe a condition. I am not very familiar with htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Is apache your web server.  If the answer is yes, You should first check your loaded apache modules to see if the rewrite module is loaded. If not , then try to add this line:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

to your apache config files . Then try to restart your web server to check if the rewirte rules worked.